# iteration over the array list and storing it contents

Tags: java

I am iterating over arraylist which is coming in this fashion

```
   elamentData=Object[10]
      [0]= Object[2]
        [0]="AAA"
        [1]="111"
      [1] = Object[2]   
         [0]="BBB"
         [1]="222"
```

so i am further storing all the contents in this below fashion that is all in resultlist arraylist

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Object[]> listObj = (List<Object[]>)query.getResultList();
        for(Object[] obj: listObj){
            for (Object o : obj) {
                resultList.add(String.valueOf(o));
            }
        }
        return resultList;
```

Now in some other part of the program i have to iterate over this resultList in the fashion that

String Product;
String Price;

```
 Product = "AAA" //In first iteration
 Price= "111"
```

then in second iteration

```
     Product = "BBB" //In first iteration
     Price= "222"
```

so I have to iterate in this fashion so that at each iteration i can iterate the product and price, so please advise how to achieve this

Comment: What is the usecase? What is the final result you expect?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Thanks , sir i have to check that if the product is zzz and price is 999 then in that case I have to break

Comment: So what is the issue now you are facing?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala sir I am not able to perform this request you to please show me how to achieve the above condition

Comment: What is the input data structure? How do you represent `Product` and `Price`? Is it in that `Object[]` and you get a `List` of them?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala these both are normal String type , the return list is of type string itself

Comment: So show me the source data structure?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala sir i have posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class `Product` that contains `name` and `price`

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String price; // maybe this should be a number

    public Product(String name, String price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Then instead of storing everything into a `List<String>` you can use a `List<Product>`

```
List<Produc> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object[]> listObj = (List<Object[]>)query.getResultList();
    for(Object[] obj: listObj){
        String name = String.valueOf(obj[0]);
        String price = String.valueOf(obj[1]);
        resultList.add(new Product(name, price);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Then when you need to traverse through the list you can do something among the lines of:

```
for(Product prod : resultList) {
    System.out.printf("Name = %s, Price = %s%n", prod.getName(), prod.getPrice());
}
```